Migrating Cassandra cluster between different AWS accounts
Note: The two different accounts could be as well two different physical locations. I would expect the answer to not change based on such a detail.
I have a DSE 5.1.x production cluster of 6 nodes + opscenter, running in account Acc1. For different reasons, this account will be shut down and I need to "move" the cluster to a different AWS account, say Acc2. Note: both accounts are in the same region.
I'm trying to come up with the quickest and smoothest way possible -no cluster-wide downtime. Would the following procedure be effective? sound?

Scale out the cluster by adding 6 new nodes all located in Acc2. Assume same DSE version, same DC and rack configs, and a VPC peering allowing new and old nodes to see each other fine.
Scale in the cluster by decommissioning the old 6 nodes in Acc1
Move "somehow" Opscenter server to Acc2. I'm guessing I could just clone the volumes onto Acc2
Some likely post-migration rolling repair + cleanup

It seems straightforward a procedure to me right now, but I want to make sure there is no fatal flaw to it.
References to such a change would also be helpful.

Adding nodes in the second AWS account as a new logical Cassandra DC is certainly a good idea. Hopefully the DCs in the two accounts are in the same region to make it much simpler.
Before you get started, remember to configure the app to use local consistencies such as LOCAL_QUORUM. Otherwise, the requests can span replicas across the two DCs. Similarly, make sure the driver's load balancing policy only uses local hosts so it doesn't use remote coordinators.
The procedure is pretty much identical to Adding a datacenter to a cluster; it's just that the new DC happens to belong another AWS account.
With OpsCenter, there's no data to migrate if you're storing it on the same DSE (as opposed to the OpsCenter data being stored in a separate cluster). You'll just need to update the replication factor for the OpsCenter keyspace in the same way that you do with the application keyspace(s). Cheers!

Thanks for the link on the load balancing. Precisely because of details like this seem key only when using a different datacenter in the second account, my question was about not using a DC. Are you indeed recommending using a different DC as opposed to adding the new nodes within the same dc? From a configurational point of view, the latter seems way easier. I just can't tell yet what's best rel. risks/benefits...

Also, while opscenter keyspace would as well be migrated in such a process, I take it the actual opscenter server will require a rebuilt in the new account. I'm guessing this, however, should be straightforward by just "moving", eg. cloning, its volumes from Acc1 to a new instance in Acc2.
